# He came to the company for less than one year

Tags: prepositions, time

> Although he came to the company **for less than one year**, he has
> learned a lot.

Is this sentence correct, especially the preposition "for"? Or what preposition should I use?

Assume today is January 7, 2023. He came to the company in February or March 2022, so it's less than one year.

Comment: If he's still here, _he has been with the company for less than a year_ would be more natural.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, he's still here. But is _he has been **in** the company_ OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*He came to the company for less than a year* suggests that his 11-month stint is now over.

If he still works for the company, it would be more natural to say *He has been with the company for less than a year.*

**In** is possible, but remember that *in the company of* has another meaning.